# Is it possible to create a proxy controller that ignores some part of the URI

Tags: spring

I have a spring service with multiple controllers with following request mapping running on port `9000`

`/api/fruits`
`/api/vegetables`
`/api/plants`

Given all these requests are being served at `localhost:9000`,is it possible via some Spring entity, that a request to `localhost:9000/{Account_id}/api/fruits` is routed to `localhost:9000/api/fruits`. I know the question is a little vague but I'm trying to see if I can add a proxy controller with mapping `/{account_id}/` which ignores the rest of the uri and have some code there to forward it to the appropriate controller. Not sure if Spring interceptor or filter of some sort would be helpful here for me to modify the request and change the URI

Comment: why you want do it in spring? Do it in Nginx for example

Comment: @Scrobot I wanted to know if its possible to do it in spring